# Error syntax in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I received a postgresql file, and while getting my feet wet (complete newbie by the way) trying to execute the sql, pgAdmin throws this error:

```
COPY userinformation (id, data, serialnumber, extra) FROM stdin;
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
>
> LINE 50: 1 MKkJhjCCB26ggAwwIBAhGF      50.70.40.90.90 \F

This is the table definition

```
CREATE TABLE userinformation (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    data text NULL,
    serialnumber character varying(150) NULL,
    extra json
);
```

I tried surrounding with single quotes, double quotes but gives the same error.

what is missing here? I'm told it should work as is.

Using version 9.5.13, the file was generated with 9.5.12

Comment: pgAdmin is not the PostgreSQL (atleast slice it become python/web) use `psql` instead.

Comment: It would be interesting what the line *before* the one that causes the error is.

Comment: well, line 50 means it is processing the stdin. I did not know it can either...